# Webgl or graphics card problem with the shader effect

Tags: html, webgl

I'm trying to launch the cool [WebGL sea shader](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Ms2SD1) created by shaderfx developer tdmaav. Later the shader was adapted for the [Construct 2](https://www.construct.net/en/forum/extending-construct-2/effects-31/effect-seascape-116007) engine. For most users the Construct 2 implementation displays normally, and looks like this:

[image: Construct 2 seascape effect]

If I launch the effect with the Construct 2, sea  colors and reflection display improperly:

[image: effect problem]

I thought it was the Nvidea videocard problem, later I tried to use the effect with radeon rx560 videocard but got the same thing.
The C2 effect creator tried to modify the effect for me, but it doesn't help. 
Does anyone have an idea what causes the problem with colors? is it still a videocard problem or something else? Maybe the reflection causes the trouble.

The code of the shader for Construct 2

```html
// "Seascape" by Alexander Alekseev aka TDM - 2014
// License Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License.
/// Gigatron the magnificient Gls attempt !
///  For Scirra Construct2 
// 
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif
 

uniform mediump sampler2D samplerFront;
varying vec2 vTex;

uniform mediump float seconds;
uniform mediump float date;
uniform mediump float pixelWidth;
uniform mediump float pixelHeight;
vec2 iResolution = vec2( 1./pixelWidth, 1./pixelHeight);
uniform mediump float scale_x;
uniform mediump float scale_y;
 

uniform float xx,yy,mspeed;   
// colors sea - base
uniform float sbred,sbgreen,sbblue;
// colors sea water color 
uniform float swred,swgreen,swblue;


const int NUM_STEPS = 6;// 8
const float PI   = 3.1415;
const float EPSILON = 1e-3;
float EPSILON_NRM = 0.1 / iResolution.x;

// sea
const int ITER_GEOMETRY = 3;
const int ITER_FRAGMENT = 5;
uniform float SEA_HEIGHT;//0.6
uniform float SEA_CHOPPY;//4.0
uniform float SEA_SPEED;//2.0
uniform  float SEA_FREQ;//0.16
//const vec3 SEA_BASE = vec3(0.1,0.19,0.22); // removed
//const vec3 SEA_WATER_COLOR = vec3(0.8,0.9,0.6); // removed replaced by uniform vars !! gtr

vec3 SEA_BASE = vec3(sbred,sbgreen,sbblue);
vec3 SEA_WATER_COLOR = vec3(swred,swgreen,swblue);

float SEA_TIME = seconds * SEA_SPEED;
mat2 octave_m = mat2(1.6,1.2,-1.2,1.6);


 
const vec4 cHashA4 = vec4 (0., 1., 57., 58.);
const vec3 cHashA3 = vec3 (1., 57., 113.);
const float cHashM = 43758.54;


vec2 Hashv2f (float p)
{
  return fract (sin (p + cHashA4.xy) * cHashM);
}

vec4 Hashv4f (float p)
{
  return fract (sin (p + cHashA4) * cHashM);
}

vec4 Hashv4v3 (vec3 p)
{
  const vec3 cHashVA3 = vec3 (37.1, 61.7, 12.4);
  const vec3 e = vec3 (1., 0., 0.);
  return fract (sin (vec4 (dot (p + e.yyy, cHashVA3), dot (p + e.xyy, cHashVA3),
     dot (p + e.yxy, cHashVA3), dot (p + e.xxy, cHashVA3))) * cHashM);
}

float Noiseff (float p)
{
  vec2 t;
  float ip, fp;
  ip = floor (p);
  fp = fract (p);
  fp = fp * fp * (3. - 2. * fp);
  t = Hashv2f (ip);
  return mix (t.x, t.y, fp);
}

float Noisefv2 (vec2 p)
{
  vec4 t;
  vec2 ip, fp;
  ip = floor (p);
  fp = fract (p);
  fp = fp * fp * (3. - 2. * fp);
  t = Hashv4f (dot (ip, cHashA3.xy));
  return mix (mix (t.x, t.y, fp.x), mix (t.z, t.w, fp.x), fp.y);
}

float Noisefv3a (vec3 p)
{
  vec4 t1, t2;
  vec3 ip, fp;
  ip = floor (p);
  fp = fract (p);
  fp = fp * fp * (3. - 2. * fp);
  t1 = Hashv4v3 (ip);
  t2 = Hashv4v3 (ip + vec3 (0., 0., 1.));
  return mix (mix (mix (t1.x, t1.y, fp.x), mix (t1.z, t1.w, fp.x), fp.y),
              mix (mix (t2.x, t2.y, fp.x), mix (t2.z, t2.w, fp.x), fp.y), fp.z);
}

float Fbm1 (float p)
{
  float f, a;
  f = 0.;
  a = 1.;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
    f += a * Noiseff (p);
    a *= 0.5;
    p *= 2.;
  }
  return f;
}

float Fbm2 (vec2 p)
{
  float f, a;
  f = 0.;
  a = 1.;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
    f += a * Noisefv2 (p);
    a *= 0.5;
    p *= 2.;
  }
  return f;
}

float Fbm3 (vec3 p)
{
  const mat3 mr = mat3 (0., 0.8, 0.6, -0.8, 0.36, -0.48, -0.6, -0.48, 0.64);
  float f, a;
  f = 0.;
  a = 1.;
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i ++) {
    f += a * Noisefv3a (p);
    a *= 0.5;
    p *= 4. * mr;
  }
  return f;
}

float Fbmn (vec3 p, vec3 n)
{
  vec3 s;
  float a;
  s = vec3 (0.);
  a = 1.;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
    s += a * vec3 (Noisefv2 (p.yz), Noisefv2 (p.zx), Noisefv2 (p.xy));
    a *= 0.5;
    p *= 2.;
  }
  return dot (s, abs (n));
}
vec3 qHit, sunDir, cloudDisp, waterDisp;
float tCur;
int idObj;
const float dstFar = 100.;

vec3 SkyBg (vec3 rd)
{
  return mix (vec3 (0.2, 0.2, 0.9), vec3 (0.45, 0.45, 0.6),
     1. - max (rd.y, 0.));
}


 




// math
mat3 fromEuler(vec3 ang) {
 vec2 a1 = vec2(sin(ang.x),cos(ang.x));
    vec2 a2 = vec2(sin(ang.y),cos(ang.y));
    vec2 a3 = vec2(sin(ang.z),cos(ang.z));
    mat3 m;
    m[0] = vec3(a1.y*a3.y+a1.x*a2.x*a3.x,a1.y*a2.x*a3.x+a3.y*a1.x,-a2.y*a3.x);
 m[1] = vec3(-a2.y*a1.x,a1.y*a2.y,a2.x);
 m[2] = vec3(a3.y*a1.x*a2.x+a1.y*a3.x,a1.x*a3.x-a1.y*a3.y*a2.x,a2.y*a3.y);
 return m;
}
float hash( vec2 p ) {
 float h = dot(p,vec2(127.1,311.7)); 
    return fract(sin(h)*43758.5453123);
}
float noise( in vec2 p ) {
    vec2 i = floor( p );
    vec2 f = fract( p ); 
 vec2 u = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);
    return -1.0+2.0*mix( mix( hash( i + vec2(0.0,0.0) ), 
                     hash( i + vec2(1.0,0.0) ), u.x),
                mix( hash( i + vec2(0.0,1.0) ), 
                     hash( i + vec2(1.0,1.0) ), u.x), u.y);
}

// lighting
float diffuse(vec3 n,vec3 l,float p) {
    return pow(dot(n,l) * 0.4 + 0.6,p);
}
float specular(vec3 n,vec3 l,vec3 e,float s) {    
    float nrm = (s + 8.0) / (3.1415 * 8.0);
    return pow(max(dot(reflect(e,n),l),0.0),s) * nrm;
}

// sky
vec3 getSkyColor(vec3 e) {
    e.y = max(e.y,0.0);
    vec3 ret;
    ret.x = pow(1.0-e.y,2.0);
    ret.y = 1.0-e.y;
    ret.z = 0.6+(1.0-e.y)*0.4;
    return ret;
}

// sea
float sea_octave(vec2 uv, float choppy) {
    uv += noise(uv);        
    vec2 wv = 1.0-abs(sin(uv));
    vec2 swv = abs(cos(uv));    
    wv = mix(wv,swv,wv);
    return pow(1.0-pow(wv.x * wv.y,0.65),choppy);
}

float map(vec3 p) {
    float freq = SEA_FREQ;//0.16
    float amp = SEA_HEIGHT;
    float choppy = SEA_CHOPPY;
    vec2 uv = p.xz; uv.x *= 0.75;
    
    float d, h = 0.0;    
    for(int i = 0; i < ITER_GEOMETRY; i++) {        
     d = sea_octave((uv+SEA_TIME)*freq,choppy);
     d += sea_octave((uv-SEA_TIME)*freq,choppy);
        h += d * amp;        
     uv *= octave_m; freq *= 1.9; amp *= 0.22;
        choppy = mix(choppy,1.0,0.2);
    }
    return p.y - h;
}

float map_detailed(vec3 p) {
    float freq = SEA_FREQ;
    float amp = SEA_HEIGHT;
    float choppy = SEA_CHOPPY;
    vec2 uv = p.xz; uv.x *= 0.75;
    
    float d, h = 0.0;    
    for(int i = 0; i < ITER_FRAGMENT; i++) {        
     d = sea_octave((uv+SEA_TIME)*freq,choppy);
     d += sea_octave((uv-SEA_TIME)*freq,choppy);
        h += d * amp;        
     uv *= octave_m; freq *= 1.9; amp *= 0.22;
        choppy = mix(choppy,1.0,0.2);
    }
    return p.y - h;
}

vec3 getSeaColor(vec3 p, vec3 n, vec3 l, vec3 eye, vec3 dist) {  
    float fresnel = 1.0 - max(dot(n,-eye),0.0);
    fresnel = pow(fresnel,3.0) * 0.65;
        
    vec3 reflected = getSkyColor(reflect(eye,n));    
    vec3 refracted = SEA_BASE + diffuse(n,l,80.0) * SEA_WATER_COLOR * 0.12; 
    
    vec3 color = mix(refracted,reflected,fresnel);
    
    float atten = max(1.0 - dot(dist,dist) * 0.001, 0.0);
    color += SEA_WATER_COLOR * (p.y - SEA_HEIGHT) * 0.18 * atten;
    
    color += vec3(specular(n,l,eye,60.0));
    
    return color;
}

// tracing
vec3 getNormal(vec3 p, float eps) {
    vec3 n;
    n.y = map_detailed(p);    
    n.x = map_detailed(vec3(p.x+eps,p.y,p.z)) - n.y;
    n.z = map_detailed(vec3(p.x,p.y,p.z+eps)) - n.y;
    n.y = eps;
    return normalize(n);
}

float heightMapTracing(vec3 ori, vec3 dir, out vec3 p) {  
    float tm = 0.0;
    float tx = 1000.0;    
    float hx = map(ori + dir * tx);
    if(hx > 0.0) return tx;   
    float hm = map(ori + dir * tm);    
    float tmid = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STEPS; i++) {
        tmid = mix(tm,tx, hm/(hm-hx));                   
        p = ori + dir * tmid;                   
     float hmid = map(p);
  if(hmid < 0.0) {
         tx = tmid;
            hx = hmid;
        } else {
            tm = tmid;
            hm = hmid;
        }
    }
    return tmid;
}

#define AA 1
// main
void main() {
 vec2 uv = vTex;
    uv = uv * 2.0 - 1.0;
 uv.y =1.-uv.y;
    uv.x *= iResolution.x / iResolution.y;    
    float time = seconds * 0.3 /*+ iMouse.x*0.01*/;
    

    //  AntiAlias
   // for( int mm=0; mm<AA; mm++ )
  //  for( int nn=0; nn<AA; nn++ )
        
    // ray
    vec3 ang = vec3(0.,yy ,xx);  
    vec3 ori = vec3(mspeed,3.5,5.0);
    vec3 dir = normalize(vec3(uv.xy,2.0)); //dir.z += length(uv) * 0.15*((-.1*iMouse.y/iResolution.y));
    dir = normalize(dir) * fromEuler(ang);
    
    // tracing
    vec3 p;
    heightMapTracing(ori,dir,p);
    vec3 dist = p - ori;
    vec3 n = getNormal(p, dot(dist,dist) * EPSILON_NRM);
    vec3 light = normalize(vec3(0.0,1.0,0.8)); 
             
    // color  // sky color not yet added !!!
    vec4 color = mix(
        vec4(SkyBg(dir),0.),
        vec4(0.,getSeaColor(p,n,light,dir,dist)),
     pow(smoothstep(0.0,-0.05,dir.y),0.3));
     
 //color *=SkyHrzCol (ori, dir);
    // post
 gl_FragColor = vec4(pow(color,vec4(0.75)));
    gl_FragColor.w = 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's neither a WebGL nor a graphics card problem.
I pasted the shader on [glsl-sandbox](http://glslsandbox.com/e), substituted the uniforms by hardcoded values and found the error to be in the code:

```
vec4 color = mix(
        vec4(SkyBg(dir),0.),
>>>>>>> vec4(0.,getSeaColor(p,n,light,dir,dist)),
        pow(smoothstep(0.0,-0.05,dir.y),0.3)
);
```

needs to be `vec4(getSeaColor(p,n,light,dir,dist),0.)`.

Also here's the obligatory shadertoy and glsl-sandbox disclaimer: this uses very inefficient techniques due to the artificial limitations imposed by the aforementioned platforms.

Comment: You are absolute right, the line mentioned caused the problem, thanks a lot.